# Windows lowest level socket programming?

Tags: c++, windows, pinvoke, winsock, sockets

I'm having a little bit of confusion regarding how low-level winsock is? I am wanting to write a VERY basic client-server program on windows. I don't really wish to use a bloated TCP or even UDP, just something extremely basic and low latency. Would winsock be ideal for this? Or is winsock the same as the windows network functions, just all packaged up (and possibly slower)? Would I be better just using PInvoke on the native windows networking functions?

Comment: TCP and UDP "bloated?" Are you nuts? Next you're going to say that IP is too high-level.

Comment: Winsock is fairly low level. I would not write off UDP so quickly. If you want a light/agile protocol, UDP is your man (definitely lighter than TCP). What is the alternative? Do you plan on writing your own protocol over generic IP?

Comment: @Matt, the 'bloated' was at TCP- TCP is slower because you get the redundancy, checks, three-way handshake etc

Comment: I believe the Winsock functions simply allow you to communicate over UDP/TCP.  You can get lower level if you want to write your own network device driver.  However, I think that is the opposite direction you want to go...

Comment: @TheBuzzSaw, to be honest I just want to send a piece of data from one computer, to another, using my own written programmes. Whatever is the fastest way of achieving that on windows?

Comment: @Chad, i think i'll avoid drivers for now- it was a pain in the backside last time to try and get them working

Comment: If that is your goal, use UDP. The thing I like about UDP is that it is "connectionless". You can just start sending data. The other system can just start listening. It should accomplish what you are after. Don't dig down to a lower level until you fully understand the implications. TCP and UDP work great.

Comment: @user997112 If you need the additional capabilities that TCP offers, you won't get them cheaper since I think we can all assume that you won't produce better code than one of the most optimized functions of windows (additional benefit: has been tested by millions of users). If you don't need the additional stuff UDP is as basic as you can get (well you could remove the ECC, but that'd be nuts..) and you won't implement UDP better than the original implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Winsock, TCP, UDP, and any well received networking library built on top of these are all going to be comparable performance wise.

Use whichever one is easiest to get your work done.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it's possible to write completely new protocol w/o implementing network driver. For this you have [raw sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_socket). On desktop Windows they are [very limited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (find "limitations").

It's possible, but not recommended. Don't reinvent the wheel and choose between UDP and TCP until you're completely sure you need something more sophisticated (but not simpler).

To send data over network (as opposite to direct cable link between two computers) you need IP protocol. To dispatch your data to right application you need transport protocol (UDP, TCP and others). [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) is almost the simplest possible one because that's was its main design goal. UDP provides additional addressing (port number in addition to IP address to deliver your data to right socket), packet boundaries ("length" field) and optional checksum. That's all and that's the minimum feature list. Take it and implement everything you need over UDP.

Next, if you need to be sure that your packets are delivered instead of silently dropped somewhere on the way (reliability), delivered in right order, if you'd like to know that somebody still listen to you on opposite end (connectivity) and other things implemented by best specialists, with hardware adapted to this implementation, tested by millions during decades, with lots of documentation, available on almost all possible platforms - use TCP.